# Deleting an item from a listbox and data source c#

Tags: c#, sql, webforms

Im trying to delete an item from both a listbox and the data table, im struggling to do this though. I can currently get it to delete from the list box, but I dont know how to delete it from the table.

Heres my code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if this is the first time th page is displayed
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //update the list box
            DisplayToDoList();
        }
    }

//this function populates the list box with to do list items
//it returns the number of records in the list
Int32 DisplayToDoList()
{
    //var to store the record count
    Int32 RecordCount;
    //create an instance of the todo class
    clsToDoList MyList = new clsToDoList();
    //get the count of records
    RecordCount = MyList.Count;
    //var to store the index
    Int32 Index = 0;
    //var to store the primary key
    Int32 ToDoNo;
    //var to store the to do text
    String ToDo;
    //clear the list
    lstToDo.Items.Clear();
    //loop through each record
    while (Index < RecordCount)
    {
        //get the primary key
        ToDoNo = MyList.List[Index].ToDoNo;
        //get the text
        ToDo = MyList.List[Index].ToDo;
        //create a new entry for the list
        ListItem NewEntry = new ListItem(ToDo, Convert.ToString(ToDoNo));
        //add the entry to the list box
        lstToDo.Items.Add(NewEntry);
        //increment the indez
        Index++;

    }

    //return the number of records 
    return RecordCount;
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//add value from textbox to listbox
lstToDo.Items.Add(txtToDo.Text);

}


protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.lstToDo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        this.lstToDo.Items.RemoveAt(this.lstToDo.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Code for clsToDoList

public class clsToDoList
{
    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
                Int32 RecordCount;
                clsDataConnection MyConnection = new clsDataConnection();
                MyConnection.Execute("sproc_tblToDo_SelectAll");
                RecordCount = MyConnection.Count;
                return RecordCount;

```
    }


    }


public List<clsToDoItem>List
{
    get
    {
        List<clsToDoItem> NewList = new List<clsToDoItem>();
        Int32 RecordCount;
        Int32 Index = 0;
        clsDataConnection MyConnection = new clsDataConnection();
        MyConnection.Execute("sproc_tblToDo_SelectAll");
        RecordCount = MyConnection.Count;

        while (Index < RecordCount)
        {
            clsToDoItem BlankPage = new clsToDoItem();
            BlankPage.ToDoNo = Convert.ToInt32(MyConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["ToDoNo"]);
            BlankPage.ToDo = Convert.ToString(MyConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["ToDo"]);
            NewList.Add(BlankPage);
            Index++;
        }

        return NewList;
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: What table are we talking about? A SQL table or some other data source?

Comment: Create a method which will acces your DataBase and remove your row and then update the list. and you will call this method in your `btnDelete_Click` method

Comment: Could you show the code of your class `MyList`. From there you can get help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and set the value equal to whatever item is selected.

```
string _itemToDelete

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (this.lstToDo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{  
   _itemToDelete = this.1stToDo.items.SelectedIndex.ToString() // or text cant remember
   this.lstToDo.Items.RemoveAt(this.lstToDo.SelectedIndex);

   connect to SQL Table       

   "DELETE FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE" + "_itemToDelete"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
public static void Delete(int ID)
{
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
        conn.connectionString = "";
conn.open();    
sqlcommand sc = new sqlcommand();
        sc.connection = conn;

        sc.commandText = "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = @ID";

        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);


        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.close()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel:

```
    public MyList Items { get; private set; }

    public ICommand Delete { get; private set; }

private void delete(object sender)
{
 var item = sender as ItemType;

 if (item == null)
   return;
  MyList.RemoveOnSubmit(item);
  YourDataContextSQL.SubmitChanges();
}
```

View:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Delete"
                        Command="{Binding Delete}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```